# Structure of a vector in python

Tags: python, numpy, memory, vector, dimension

How can I identify a vector in Python?
Like does it have a single dimension or is it n-dimensions, I got really confused when trying to understand this in NumPy.

Also, what's the difference between static memory allocation and a dynamic one in vectors?

Comment: python doesn't have a vector data type. I added the numpy tag to your question, so that you get answers about how numpy handles vectors.

Comment: `numpy` has `ndarray`; it does not formally have `vectors` (the word is rare in its docs).  What people think of as 'vectors' may have shape (n,), or (n,1) for 'column vector' or (1,n) for row vector.  `numpy` intros should cover `shape` and memory allocation adequately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector has a single dimension and is create with method such as numpy.array and numpylinspace. A n-dimension array would be a matrix created with methods such as zeros or numpy.random.uniform(...). You  dont have to use numpy to use vectors in python. You can simply use the basic array type.

In python you usually dont have to worry about memory allocation. A dynamic memory allocation means that elements can added or removed to the vector whereas in a static memory allocation, there would be a fixed number of elements in the vector.

Comment: Ah so basically in python I don't have to worry about anything that would be static in other languages since most things are dynamic.
thank you!